# Seleção Utilizando FROM TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma tabela e uma função que retorna um pipeline, só que a função precisa receber um dado da primeira tabela, imaginei que a seleção seria algo assim:

```
Select FERRAMENTA.IDFERRAMENTAS
 FROM SIG_SERVICOSFERRAMENTAS FERRAMENTA
INNER JOIN TABLE(SELECT TEXTO1,DATA1,DATA2 FROM TABLE(LIDER.PKG_EQP.FN_FERRAMENTA_ETQ(FERRAMENTA.IDFERRAMENTAS))) VALIDADE
 ON 1 = 1
```

e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> FERRAMENTA.IDFERRAMENTAS idenficador invalido

Ja fiz consultas semelhantes, sei que o erro deve ser algo pequeno na seleção, mas estou sem conseguir acha-lo.

Comment: FERRAMENTA e IDFERRAMENTA são dois campos de SIG_SERVICOSFERRAMENTAS ? Se sim, troca '.' por ','

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O escopo do seu segundo subselect (`SELECT TEXTO1,DATA1,DATA2...`) não consegue "enxergar" o campo `FERRAMENTA.IDFERRAMENTAS`.

Tente retira-lo e veja se obtem o resultado esperado, da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT FERRAMENTA.IDFERRAMENTAS
FROM SIG_SERVICOSFERRAMENTAS FERRAMENTA
INNER JOIN TABLE(LIDER.PKG_EQP.FN_FERRAMENTA_ETQ(FERRAMENTA.IDFERRAMENTAS)) VALIDADE
ON 1 = 1
```

Comment: Resolver, eu so queria otimizar a seleção e não traqzer os outros camps que não vou utilizar, achei que fazendo uma outra seleção era possível Obrigado.